# getJSON com parametro

Tags: jquery

Estou realizando uma consulta com getJSON chamando o controler MVC podendo retornar um JsonResult.
Quando passo uma letra para fazer a busca pela primeira vez o controller é acionado e retorna o valor filtrado pela letra infomada, porém se eu apagar essa letra do campo e digita-lá novamente, o controller não é mais acionado e o getJSON de alguma forma armazenou a primeira consulta e exibe o resultado retornado da primeira consulta novamente.

Segue o trecho.

```
$.getJSON("/Funcionalidade/FindWithByTelaTop", { Id_Sistema: id_sistema, Id_Grupo: $("#GrupoIdUpd").val(), Filtro: filtro, Top: 7 }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data.Records, function (i, item) {

                        TblTelaAddRow(item);
                        hasRow = true;
                    });

                    if (hasRow == false) {
                        if ($("#spanMessage").html().length == 0) {
                            $("#spanMessage").html("A consulta não retornou resultados");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ($("#spanMessage").html().length > 0) {
                            $("#spanMessage").html("");
                        }
                    }
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
                });
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult FindWithByTelaTop(int Id_Sistema, int Id_Grupo, string Filtro = "", int Top = 10)
        {
            try
            {
                var dados = _funcionalidadeModels.find(Id_Sistema, Id_Grupo, Filtro)               
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        x.Id,
                        x.Tela                        
                    }).AsParallel();

                if (dados != null)
                {
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        Result = "OK",
                        Records = dados.OrderBy(o => o.Tela).Take(Top),
                        TotalRecordCount = dados.Count()
                    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    string msg = "Erro ao tentar obter lista. Objeto nulo.";
                    return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Records = msg }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = "Erro ao tentar consultar lista de clientes. Info: " + ex.Message;
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    msg += ". Exceção interna: " + ex.InnerException.Message;
                }
                return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Records = msg }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Qual é o código que chama esse `$.getJSON`? Sabes se o teu problema está no servidor ou no lado do cliente?

Comment: O evento é disparado pelo keydown do campo de edição do filtro.A cada letra digitada é pra realizar a busca. Acredito q isso seja uma característica mais não  sei como contornar. Esse comportamento está apresentando em dev, não hospedei a página, acredito q deve ter o mesmo comportamento. Se eu digitar uma letra diferente da primeira vez o controle é acionado, mais voltando a apresentar o memo problema se digitar ela novamente. Imagino que o problema seja do lado do cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Olá

Conseguir resolver esse problema.
Descobrir após muitas pesquisas que alguns navegadores mantem em cache esses filtros, e para contornar o problema é necessário fazer o seguinte.

Caso esteja usando o `$.ajax` deve ser incluído o `cache = false` e para o `$.getJSON` tem que ser incluído mais um parâmetro `new Date().getTime()`.
Isso vai fazer com que sempre seja alterado consulta que esteja sendo passado para o controller forçando o navegador a realizar a busca.